# Maven deploying twice

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-assembly-plugin

I am having an issue where my artifact is deploying twice when I run

```
mvn deploy

[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (deploy-file) @ 1.0 ---
Uploading to ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/https/1.0-https.zip
Uploaded to ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/https/1.0-https.zip (334 MB at 8.1 MB/s)
Uploading to ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/https/1.0-https.pom
Uploaded to ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/https/1.0-https.pom (423 B at 795 B/s)
Downloading from ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/maven-metadata.xml (310 B at 1.5 kB/s)
Uploading to ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded to ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/maven-metadata.xml (336 B at 614 B/s)
Uploading to ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/https/1.0-https.zip
Uploaded to ProductSuite: http://abc.123:8081/nexus/repository/ProductSuite/Dev/Release/webUI/1.0/https/1.0-https.zip (334 MB at 7.2 MB/s)
```

After looking up some fixes for this I came across a potential fix:

I would simply have to added the following to the maven-assembly-plugin

```
<attach>false</attach>

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:04 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-05T16:10:44-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project 11.8: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]
```

Below is what I'm currently working with. It works without the attach configuration but fails with it in there.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>Dev.Release.productA</groupId>
   <artifactId>11.8</artifactId>
   <version>https</version>
   <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
      <COMPANYRepositoryUrl>http://abc.123:8081/nexus</COMPANYRepositoryUrl>
      <product>productA</product>
   </properties>
      <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
     <id>PROD</id>
     <url>${PRODRepositoryUrl}/repository/PROD/</url>
  </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
       <!--
        | Where to deploy our built artifacts.
        + -->
              <build>
          <!--
          | Define versions of plugins to ensure stable builds.
          +
            -->
          <plugins>
             <!--
              | Standard maven plugins.
              | Note: enforcer plugin is used (initialize) to ensure all plugins are versioned
              | Or use $ mvn enforcer:enforce" to check
              | Note: to check on the latest version of plugins available do:
              | $ mvn versions:display-plugin-updates
              + -->


      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <executions>
        <execution>
               <id>default-install</id>
              <phase>none</phase>
        <configuration>
                 <file>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>            
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>default-jar</id>
              <phase>none</phase>
              <configuration>
                 <finalName>unwanted</finalName>
                 <classifier>unwanted</classifier>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <executions>
               <!-- disable standard deploy -->
               <execution>
                  <id>default-deploy</id>
                  <phase>none</phase>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <phase>deploy</phase>
                  <configuration>
                     <file>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
                     <repositoryId>TEST</repositoryId>
                     <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                     <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                     <version>${project.version}</version>
                     <url>${COMPANYRepositoryUrl}/repository/TEST/</url>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
               <attach>false</attach>
               <descriptors>
                  <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
               </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>make-assembly</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>


<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>zip</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>C:\PATH\to\webui.exe</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Why are you using deploy-file bound to life cycle? But using `<attach>false</attach>` in your maven-assembly-plugin configuration....

Comment: Why are you using maven-antrun-plugin?

Comment: You repositories from where you consume dependencies should be located into `settings.xml`  and furthermore should be configured to use your internal repository manager...

Comment: Ok, I took out the antrun plugin (it was used by an old build and no longer needed for this purpose.

I have also taken out the repositories and placed them in my settings.xml.

As for the deploy-file bound to life cycle. This pom is specifically for deploying an already packaged product -in this case an exe zipped up (only eay I could get the exe to push to Nexus). I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: The binding for deploy-plugin:deploy-file to life cycle is simply wrong. Deploying artifacts to a repository is done via `mvn deploy`. There is no need to define deploy-file... Is the appropriate zip created correctly during the build? Remove the `<attach>..</attach>` configuration and also remove the line `<appendAssemblyId>..</..>`... and check if an deploy will do the right thing.

Comment: I took out the deploy-file part and <attach>..</attach>

Comment: I left in the <appendAssemblyId>false... since it wouldn't run without it (even when I removed it from the assembly)

Comment: Now when I run mvn deploy it stops after running the maven-install-plugin. The build succeeds but does not deploy to Nexus.

Comment: Please make an example project on Github or alike...

Comment: I don't have time for that. I wish I did! I changes the <phase> for the deploy plugin to package and ran mvn clean package and got the results I was looking for

Comment: Ok. So I don't have time either...sorry..

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a section to the default execution of the maven-install-plugin. I can run mvn deploy without duplicate uploads which saves a minute in deployment time. (I also updated some of the plugins to newer versions)

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>default-install</id>
         <phase>none</phase>
         <configuration>
             <file>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```